# Presto best practices of the number of splits?

Tags: presto

There is a configuration item(`max-split-size`) to set one `split`'s max size.In other word,i can change the value of the item to change the number of splits.

I know,more splits will use more `cpu` at the same time,and the search will become faster.

If so,why presto set the default value of the item is `32M` instead of such `1M`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's overhead to each split that is created, so you don't want them to be too small. Also, some file formats like ORC can't be split smaller than the size of an ORC stripe which tends to be tens to hundreds of megabytes